# Android not fetching data from website into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, inputstreamreader

I can't make Android load a web resource into an ArrayList - whatever I do, the list is empty. If I don't run it in a thread, logcat shows a `StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork` error. In java VM this is working perfectly; the site is loaded into the list and I can get the data I want.

Here is the code:

```
public class WeatherData {
public static String data() {
    String[] tempsArr = new String[9];
    String[] minArr = new String[9];
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String[] weekDay = new String[1];
    SimpleDateFormat[] dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat[1];
    dayFormat[0] = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
    weekDay[0] = dayFormat[0].format(calendar.getTime());
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "cache.mrt.ac.lk");
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");

                //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();

                URL link = new URL("https://www.sinoptik.bg/shumen-bulgaria-100727233/10-days");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
                String inputLine;
                String[] arr;
                int count = 0;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    list.add(inputLine);
                    count++;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
                System.out.println(me);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    dayFormat[0] = new SimpleDateFormat("E");

    weekDay[0] = dayFormat[0].format(calendar.getTime());
    int idx = 0;
    for (
            int j = 0; j < list.size() - 550; j++)

    {
        if (list.get(j).contains(weekDay[0].toString())) {
            tempsArr[idx] = getNum(list.get(j + 3));
            minArr[idx] = getNum(list.get(j + 5));
            idx++;
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
            weekDay[0] = dayFormat[0].format(calendar.getTime());
        }
    }

    return tempsArr[1];
}
```

I know it needs optimization, but I want first to make it work and give me at least one value (that's why I used only one of the arrays with one index for return). I see it on debug it is connecting to the site but the ArrayList is empty and it is doing nothing.

Comment: `can't make Android to load website into ArrayList`. Android? You mean your app? Your Android app?

Comment: Typically you use an Asynctask in Android for networking

Comment: Yes, when I run the app it gives me "null" value from this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 thread.start();
```

You cannot have code after you started the thread as that code will be executed directly and in parallel with the code in the thread. So it is possible that that code is finished even before there is a connectiopn with the website. No wonder your arraylist is empty.

You have to put that code in a separate function and only call that function after the thread has finished.

Comment: If I don't use thread it gives me error as I said in the beginning. Even when I "override" error with this 

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
It still does nothing.

Comment: @Rado, the answer does not state that you shouldn't use a thread, you have to since you are making a network call. It is saying that you should populate your ArrayList within the thread

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. The problem was with the "https" connection, when I changed it to "http" it downloaded the site. But there was another problem - it loaded the mobile version?!? It took me a while to figure this out - "http://m.sinoptik.bg/shumen-bulgaria-100727233/10-days" and I had to make some adjustment to data fetching algorithm to match the mobile site, but now it is fine. The data is the same as the original site minus ~700 lines of data less, which is even better :)